# How to type cast

Tags: haskell, casting

C#:

```
static int F(object x)
{
 return x is string ? 1 : 2;
}
```

**Haskell?**
The tricky bit seems to me that Haskell does not have a root type *object*.

Edited: I do not care about converting to string. I want to know how to typecast (for example to see if an *object* is a *Customer* or an *Order*.

Comment: The idea of casting an arbitrary type into another does not make much sense in Haskell (or any language for that matter). It makes sense for some specific pairs of types (integer to string, integer to float, etc., for which Haskell has appropriate functions `show`, `fromIntegral` etc.) or for types between which you have defined conversion functions, in which case you use them.

Comment: I think it does make sense. Maybe i do not want to create a virtual method in my class hierarchy to separate two concerns. So i have to to an explicit type-switch elsewhere.

Comment: It is not good practice however.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Haskell, all types that allow a conversion to a string instantiate the `Show` typeclass which provides

```
show :: Show a => a -> String
```

So your whole code is nothing but

```
f x = show x
```

or

```
f = show
```

with the same generic type `f :: Show a => a -> String` (Forall types `a` that are conversible to a string, take a value of this type and return a string).

Note that you don't have to do an explicit, run-time type-check like in C#; the generic template is resolved at compile-time. You don't need a polymorphic root type - A cast like in C# would in fact be somewhat complicated and against the language's conception. Instead of allowing arbitrary casts between types, it defined typeclasses for certain meaningful conversions.

Note that compatibility is checked at compile-time:

```
-- Working
f 1
f "Hallo"
f (1, 2)
f [1, 2, 3]

-- Not working
f (\x -> x + 1)
```

**In response to your edited question**:

As I said before, arbitrary conversions aren't allowed in Haskell (without very very unsafe code). And since Haskell is not object-oriented, there is no inheritance relationship that required any cast. There simply aren't meaningless `object` values that needed runtime-checking/casting. For expressing alternatives, you'll have to define a union type, a typeclass or use the `Either` type.

In what case do you encounter an object that is a `Customer` or an `Order`? A value of that type is simply nonsensical. Please clarify again.

As to your logger example:
You'll need a typeclass:

```
class Loggable a where
    writeToLog :: a -> IO ()
```

Comment: Lets say i have built a logger that wants to log everything to a text file except objects of type customer that are going to be logged to a database. I want the logging function to carry the burden of checking. I don't want the caller to call a different method depending on the object type. How the logging is being done is an implementation detail.

Comment: A typeclass does what i want. Nice.

Answer (score 20):

Dario's right, generally in Haskell you want to create a type class to dispatch on something's type. That being said, there *is* a type safe way to cast in Haskell. This is part of the [Scrap your boilerplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb) generic programming library that allows you to write the "interesting" parts of manipulations of complex nested data types while SYB fills in the blanks. Brain meltingly awesome. Here's a presentation on it in [ppt](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/hmap/Boilerplate%20v3.ppt) or [html](http://74.125.95.132/search?q=cache:X59XzxKV2LYJ:research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/hmap/Boilerplate%2520v3.ppt+haskell+generic+cast&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us).

Here's what the cast looks like:

```
cast :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => a -> Maybe b
ghci> (cast 'a') :: Maybe Char
Just 'a'
ghci> (cast 'a') :: Maybe Bool
Nothing
ghci> (cast True) :: Maybe Bool
Just True
```

Comment: Is there a functional semantics to the `::` operator? It doesn't seem to exist in the language itself, but rather some sort of compiler annotation. If so, how do I formally understand the `::` and its interaction with the cast function?

Answer (score 9):

Casting and `is`/`instanceof` make sense in languages that feature [subtyping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping). Your question can be answered in several ways:

- Haskell does not have subtyping and so `is`/`instanceof` make no sense in Haskell; there are only explicit conversions. There is no `object` type from which all types extend.
- Haskell's type classes offer ad-hoc polymorphism and help in overloading a single name for many conversions. For example (as others have pointed out) `show` is the overloaded name for converting any type to a String. Type classes can also be used to make certain conversions (seem) implicit.
- Using type classes, the authors of the generic [Scrap Your Boilerplate](http://www.cs.vu.nl/boilerplate/#papers) library have created  a *safe cast* function (also pointed out by others).

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way is to use [Data.Typeable](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.2.2/html/libraries/base/Data.Typeable.html), as Dario observes, which covers all the standard types, though you need to pass "`Deriving Typeable`", or otherwise implement `typeOf` for your own type definitions to be covered.  This is not standard Haskell 98, but it is in ghc since 6.2.2.

Your code could be realised:

```
 stringtyperep :: TypeRep
 stringtyperep = typeOf "somestring"

 F :: (Typeable 'a) =>'a -> Integer
 F x | (typeOf x == stringtyperep) = 1
 F x = 2
```

In general, OO-style type reflection is better done with generic programming, but this would not be a good example for that.

Additionally, all types in typeclass `Typeable` can be "cast" into [Data.Dynamic](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.2.2/html/libraries/base/Data.Dynamic.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have objects that can either be Customers or Orders, then you'd introduce a new datatype "Customer|Order" so that each object carries a type tag saying which it is.

I don't know the Haskell syntax offhand, but in F# it would be

```
type CustOrOrd =
    | Cust of Customer
    | Ord of Order

let F (x:CustOrOrd) : int =
    match x with
    | Cust c -> 1
    | Ord o -> 2

let thing1 = Cust someCustomer
let thing2 = Ord someOrder
// can call F on thing1 or thing2
```

More generally, in Haskell if you want to do something like a fixed OO type hierarchy (for a fixed set of highly related types, to be able to treat them as the same type in some cases), you may use a union type as above.  On the other hand, for common operations across a variety of unrelated types (like ToString/Show) you might use a Haskell type class.

Answer (score 3):

This is something I've tried before, and I don't think you can do it.

[Introduction to Haskell Pure Functions](http://onlamp.com/onlamp/2007/08/02/introduction-to-haskell-pure-functions.html)

> Haskell takes a very different
>   approach. It starts by performing type
>   analysis with a type checker to
>   understand your program at compile
>   time. **The type checker strictly
>   prohibits type casting and does not
>   allow type errors to be ignored.**
>   Because types are checked at compile
>   time, and there is no escape from the
>   type checker, Haskell is frequently
>   described as both statically typed and
>   strongly typed.

Answer (score 3):

### Define `Object` yourself

If your use-case is quite simple, it's probably best just to define the Object type yourself, thus:

```
data Type = String | Integer | List | Bool
    deriving (Eq, Show)

class Object a where
    typeOf :: a -> Type

instance Object String  where typeOf _ = String
instance Object Integer where typeOf _ = Integer
instance Object [a]     where typeOf _ = List
instance Object Bool    where typeOf _ = Bool

f :: (Object a, Num b) => a -> b
f x = if typeOf x == String then 1 else 2
```

Obviously you'll have to write an `instance` declaration for every type that you might want to use as an Object in your function that uses `typeOf`. This could get tricky when you try to define `instance`s for tuples, because in Haskell two tuples are of different types if they don't have the same number of elements, so you might have to write an infinite number of `instance` declarations, rather like this:

```
data Type = String | Integer | List | Bool | Tuple
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Object ()              where typeOf _ = Tuple
instance Object (a)             where typeOf _ = Tuple
instance Object (a,b)           where typeOf _ = Tuple
instance Object (a,b,c)         where typeOf _ = Tuple
instance Object (a,b,c,d)       where typeOf _ = Tuple
instance Object (a,b,c,d,e)     where typeOf _ = Tuple
instance Object (a,b,c,d,e,f)   where typeOf _ = Tuple
instance Object (a,b,c,d,e,f,g) where typeOf _ = Tuple
```

### Use `Data.Typeable`

If your usage gets more complicated, you might try [`Data.Typeable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Typeable.html):

```
import Data.Typeable

f :: (Typeable a, Num b) => a -> b
f x = if typeOf x == typeOf (undefined::String) then 1 else 2
```

You can replace the `(undefined::String)` with just `""` if you prefer; whichever reads easier for you.

Answer (score 2):

In C# it's likely more efficient not to do the cast:

```
return x == null ? null : x.ToString();
```

In Haskell there's the "show" type class, anything that implements the type class can have show called on it and so no casting is needed.