# How do I convert a -> Float?

Tags: haskell

I think that I could use fromEnum for a -> Int but how do I do it for a -> Float. I need my variable to be a Float for my function to work but I can't work out how to convert it? I've gone through the Prelude and can't see anything that would work. Sorry if this is a really stupid question but I'm just starting out.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894365/haskell-how-to-type-cast

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on what *a* is. If *a* is an instance of Integral, like `Int` or `Integer`, you can use

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

If *a* is an instance of Real, like Rational or Double, you can use

```
realToFrac :: (Real a, Fractional b) => a -> b
```

There are also special functions for Integer and Rational that `fromIntegral` and `realToFrac` are based on:

```
fromInteger :: (Num a) => Integer -> a
fromRational :: (Fractional a) => Rational -> a
```

If *a* is an instance of Enum (and so you can use `fromEnum`, as you said), then `fromIntegral . fromEnum` should do it. `fromEnum` converts *a* to `Int`, then `fromIntegral` converts from `Int` to `Float`, so `fromIntegral . fromEnum` converts *a* to `Float`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an `(Enum a) => a` to an `Int` first, and then the `Int` to a `Float`. To convert an `Int` to a `Float` (or many other number types), you use `fromIntegral`. A function that combines these two functions would be:

```
floatFromEnum :: (Enum a) => a -> Float
floatFromEnum = fromIntegral . fromEnum
```

**EDIT:** Note that `fromEnum` doesn't work for any `a`, as you are implying, but only works for `a`'s that are `Enum` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `fromIntegral` function?

```
fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
```

I've just tested it in `ghci`, and while the following code does not work (wrong types):

```
> let a = 1::Int
> let b = 1::Float
> a + b
Couldn't match expected type `Int' against inferred type `Float'....
```

If you use `fromIntegral`, it works just fine:

```
> let a = 1::Int
> let b = 1::Float
> (fromIntegral a) + b
2.0
```