# "enable_if" in Haskell

Tags: haskell, enable-if

How do I write something like the following in Haskell:

```
showSquare :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> String
showSquare x = "The square of " ++ (show x) ++ " is " ++ (show (x * x))

showSquare :: (Show a, not Num a) => a -> String
showSquare x = "I don't know how to square " ++ (show x)
```

Basically, something like [boost::enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) in C++.

GHC extensions are ok.

Comment: By the way, the article [Concept-controlled polymorphism](https://parasol.tamu.edu/~jarvi/papers/concept-controlled.pdf) at the Boost link has a direct comparison with Haskell's type classes (which are actually the motivation). The negation you used actually comes from the meta-compilation step involved in C++ templates (which plain Haskell doesn't do).

Answer (score 6):

Why would you want this? The typechecker makes sure that you will never call `showSquare` on something which isn't a `Num` in the first case. [There is no `instanceof` in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894384/60462), as everything is typed statically.

It doesn't work for arbitrary types: you can only define your own [type class](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html), e.g.

```
class Mine a where
  foo :: a -> String

instance (Num a) => Mine a where
  foo x = show x*x
```

And you can add more instances for other classes, but you won't be able to write just `instance Mine a` for an arbitrary `a`. An additional `instance (Show a) => ...` will also not help, as [overlapping instances](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) are also not allowed (the link describes a way to work around it, but it requires quite a bit of additional machinery).

Comment: ShiDoiSi: I want this to be resolved statically. Like how `show` can do different things for `Int`, `String`, `Tree` etc all statically.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's fair to call meta-compilation "static" :-)

Comment: For all that it's fair to emphasise to @Clinton that he really shouldn't be doing this, the “overlapping instances” link is the literal answer to his question.

Answer (score 3):

First, giving different type signature to different equations for the same function isn't possible at all. Any function can have *only one* type, regardless of how much equations it has.

Second, negative constraints does not (would not) have any sound meaning in Haskell. Recall what class constraint mean:

```
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
f x y = x + y
```

`Num a` in the type of `f` means that we can apply any class methods of `Num` type class to values of type `a`. We are consciously not naming concrete type in order to get generic behavior. Essentially, we are saying "we do not care what `a` exactly is, but we do know that `Num` operations are applicable to it". Consequently, we can use `Num` methods on `x` and `y`, but *no more than that*, that is, we cannot use *anything* except for `Num` methods on `x` and `y`. This is what type class constraints are and why are they needed. They are specifying generic interface for the function.

Now consider your imaginary `not Num a` constraint. What information does this statement bring? Well, we know that `a` should not be `Num`. However, this information is completely useless for us. Consider:

```
f :: not Num a => a -> a
f = ???
```

What can you place instead of `???`? Obviously, we know what we *cannot* place. But except for that this signature has no more information than

```
f :: a -> a
```

and the only operation `f` could be is `id` (well, `undefined` is possible too, but that's another story).

Finally consider your example:

```
showSquare :: (Show a, not Num a) => a -> String
showSquare x = "I don't know how to square " ++ (show x)
```

I do not give first part of your example intentionally, see the first sentence in my answer. You cannot have different equations with different types. But this function alone is completely useless. You can safely remove `not Num a` constraint here, and it won't change anything.

The only usage for such negative constrains in statically typed Haskell is producing compile-time errors when you supply, say, `Int` for `not Num a`-constrainted variable. But I see no use for this.

Comment: Do you know what `boost::enable_if` does, Vladimir?

Comment: Whether he does or not, his answer is still valid - `boost::enable_if` has semantics which simply don't make sense in Haskell, which has a type system that makes C++'s look lax.

Comment: @Andre, I looked through the article on `enable_if` at the link in the question and, if I understand correctly, it is some kind of specifying a domain in which template parameter can change, that is, a thing similar to type classes in Haskell. `enable_if` extends this domain, and `disable_if` shrinks it. However, type classes work completely differently than templates. They have more complicated resolve rules (especially when certain extensions are enabled). They also have completely different machinery behind their operation. This all make reasoning about this in context of Haskell useless.

Comment: @MatthewWalton I did not think his answer was invalid, but was not answering the question. I had the impression that Vladimir could improve his answer by learning more about `enable_if`.

Answer (score 3):

If I really, absolutely needed something like this (and I don't believe I ever have), I think this is the simplest approach in Haskell:

```
class Show a => ShowSquare a where
  showSquare :: a -> String
  showSquare a = "I don't know how to square " ++ (show a)

instance ShowSquare Int where
  showSquare = showSquare'

instance ShowSquare Double where
  showSquare = showSquare'

-- add other numeric type instances as necessary

-- make an instance for everything else
instance Show a => ShowSquare a

showSquare' :: (Show a, Num a) => a -> String
showSquare' x = "The square of " ++ (show x) ++ " is " ++ (show (x * x))
```

This requires overlapping instances, obviously.  Some people may complain about the required boilerplate, but it's pretty minimal.  5 or 6 instances would cover most numeric numeric types.

You could probably make something work using ideas from the [Advanced Overlap](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) wiki page.  Note that technique still requires instances to be listed explicitly, so whether it's better than this is probably a matter of taste.

It's also possible to approach the problem with template haskell, by writing a TH splice instead of a function.  The splice would have to `reify ''Num` at the call site to determine if a `Num` instance is in scope, then choose the appropriate function.  However, making this work is likely to be more trouble than just writing out the Num instances manually.

Comment: Good point that in any Haskell-solution you have to "compute" the instances manually (including realizing where to use the default implementation, which works here, but may not work in general). That's clear from the articles, but I didn't state it explicitly in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on "not a Num a" is very fragile in Haskell in a way that is not fragile in C++.

In C++ the classes are defined in one placed (closed) while Haskell type classes are open and can have instances declared in module C of data from module A and class from module B.

The (no extension) resolution of type classes has a guiding principle that importing a module like "C" would never change the previous resolution of type classes.

Code that expected "not a Num Custom" will change if any recursively imported module (e.g. from another package) defined an "instance Num Custom".

There is an additional problem with polymorphism.  Consider a function in module "D"

```
useSS :: Show a => a -> Int -> [String]
useSS a n = replicate n (showSquare a)

data Custom = Custom deriving Show
use1 :: Int -> String
use1 = useSS Custom -- no Num Custom in scope
```

Now consider a module "E" in another package which imports the above module "D"

```
instance Num Custom
use2 :: Int -> String
use2 = useSS Custom -- has a Num Custom now
```

What should `(use1 1)` and `(use2 1)` evaluate to?  Do you want to work with a language with traps like this?  Haskell is trying to prevent, by principled design, the existence of this trap.

This kind of ad hoc overloading is everywhere in C++ resolution but is exactly what Haskell was designed to avoid.  It is *possible* with GHC extensions to do such things, but one has to be careful not to create dangerous traps, and it is not encouraged.