# Function that takes a variable (of any type) and determines if said variable contains a number

Tags: function, haskell

From this same site I extracted this function that checks if a string is a number.

```
isNumeric :: String -> Bool
isNumeric ""  = False
isNumeric "." = False
isNumeric xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

Is there a way to modify the function so that instead of it checking that a string is a number, I can make it so that it checks a variable of any type?
I try this:

```
isNumeric :: Eq a => a -> Bool
isNumeric ""  = False
isNumeric "." = False
isNumeric xs  =
  case dropWhile isDigit xs of
    ""       -> True
    ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys
    _        -> False
```

Comment: It is kind of possible (you'd need to add a `Typeable a` constraint), but it is not idiomatic and also not necessary in most cases.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894365/15207568, there are a bunch of related/duplicate questions actually: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+typeable+is%3Aanswer

Comment: I think the answer most useful to the OP based on context is the single word "No.". I would not overcomplicate this with Typeable and other shenanigans.

Comment: Are you thinking about python's `isinstance(i, int)`? You don't need that in Haskell (or any static type system) as the compiler knows if something is `Int` or `Float` or `Num a`

Comment: Why would you need that? Where would you use such a function?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI 's comment may sound defensive, but I also recommend thinking about it.  Even assume that you have your desired `isNumeric` function and use it to try to do what you were going to do.  From experience, I have a suspicion that your need for it will evaporate  (but I'm curious about it if it doesn't)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Haskell code I provided to stackoverflow has a few issues:

1. The type signature `Eq a => a -> Bool` suggests that the function can take a value of any type that has an instance of the Eq type class. However, the function is clearly designed to work with strings, as it uses pattern matching with string literals like "" and ".". The type signature should be `String -> Bool`.
2. The function `isDigit` is not in scope. You need to import it from the Data.Char module.
3. The function `isNumeric` should handle negative numbers and numbers with a + sign as well.
4. In addition, In Haskell, functions are strongly typed, and the type system is designed to ensure that functions receive data of the expected type. If you want a function that can take any type of data, you would typically use a type class to define a common interface for all the types you want to handle.
5. However, Haskell's type system does not allow for a function to directly accept any type of data and then perform runtime type checking like you might do in dynamically typed languages. Instead, you would need to use a type class that all the types you want to handle would implement.
6. For the specific case of checking if a value is numeric, you could use the Real type class, which encompasses all the types that can be treated as real numbers. Here's an example of how you might define such a function:

In summary it would look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

import Data.Char (isDigit)
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

class IsNumeric a where
  isNumeric :: a -> Bool
  -- Provide a default implementation that always returns True for numeric types
  isNumeric _ = True

instance IsNumeric Char where
  isNumeric _ = False

-- You can then have instances for all `Num` types without providing a specific implementation
instance IsNumeric Int
instance IsNumeric Integer
instance IsNumeric Float
instance IsNumeric Double
-- ... and so on for other `Num` types

-- For String, you provide a specific implementation
instance IsNumeric String where
  isNumeric ""  = False
  isNumeric "." = False
  isNumeric xs
    | "-" `isPrefixOf` xs || "+" `isPrefixOf` xs = isNumeric (tail xs)
    | otherwise =
        case dropWhile isDigit xs of
          ""       -> True
          ('.':ys) -> all isDigit ys && not (null ys)
          _        -> False
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) already gets you where you need to go. If the string contains a suitable representation of a value of the type you care about, you'll get a `Just`; otherwise a `Nothing`. For example:

```
> readMaybe "3.0" :: Maybe Double
Just 3.0
> readMaybe "3.0" :: Maybe Int
Nothing
> readMaybe "True" :: Maybe Bool
Just True
> readMaybe "false" :: Maybe Bool
Nothing
> readMaybe "True but also not" :: Maybe Bool
Nothing
```